# Changing the css file by clicking on the website

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need your help , I need a button on the site that will change the css file that is already filled with other styles , how to make it easier ?

I tried button onclick in the usual way, but it didn't work out for me

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please show how you reference the original CSS.

Comment: if you want to add add classes to elements you can use `element.classList`, I am not sure if changing the contents of the css file itself is possible. This might be possible if you are using `<style>` tags and edit the content within it, but I am not sure

Answer (score 0):

One way to allow users to change the CSS styling of a webpage by clicking a button is to use JavaScript to modify the HTML  element that references the CSS file. By doing so, the new styles specified in the alternative CSS file can be applied to the webpage in response to a user's input.

You can take reference of the code snippet below for reference:

```
// HTML code for the button
<button onclick="changeCSS()">Change CSS</button>

// JavaScript code to change the CSS file
function changeCSS() {
  // Get the HTML link element that references the CSS file
  var cssLink = document.getElementById("myCSS");

  // Set the href attribute of the link element to the new CSS file
  cssLink.href = "newstyles.css";
}
```